# Why isn't this form validating with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form which is not working. I have simplified it greatly and thrown into a JSBIN :

http://jsbin.com/ifezas/edit#javascript,html

Even in this simple example, nothing validates. What gives?

Comment: What are you expecting it to validate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified any rules for how it should validate.

For example, you can add the class `required` to your inputs to make them required, or you can specify the rules like this:

```
$('#yourForm').validate({ 
    rules: { field1: 'required', field3: 'required' } 
});
```

See [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#List_of_built-in_Validation_methods) for the [list of built-in validation methods](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#List_of_built-in_Validation_methods).

Comment: Thanks Fish - i actually always define rules above as you have it but for simplicity wanted to use the basic call without defining rules. I was unaware of the 'required' class. Thanks for the help. It seems my big issue is elsewhere on my main form.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to require the inputs.

Add a class of required to them. `class='required'`.